# Android show fragment's views after http response received

Tags: android

I have a fragment and I populate its view after receiving http response. Here is what I do:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    initUI(); // initialize views
    makeHTTPRequest(); // get the data for this fragment
    return fragmentContent;
}

public boolean onServiceSuccess(ConnectionResponse response) {
   // Populate the ui with the data received
   // titleTV.setText(response.getTitle); etc.
}
```

The problem is the following: Until the response is received, I see the unpopulated views. I mean, I see an empty Button, empty ImageView, empty spinner etc. I just want to show a white blank page (without any ui elements) until response is received. I thought I could make root view invisible first then make it visible when response is received:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    rootView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    initUI();
}

public boolean onServiceSuccess(ConnectionResponse response) {
    rootView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // ...
}
```

But I do not know whether this is a good idea. It may require too much work to do it for all fragments. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to show your button and imageview, make their visibility gone in layout, and make them visible after your data is loaded.

Comment: Yeah it's possible and I do it sometimes. Another option that exist in your activity show loading and when you get Response pass response object to Fragment and populate the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ProgressDialog until data is being fetched.

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
                        progress.setTitle("Loading...!!");
                        progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                        progress.setCancelable(false);
                        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);                       
                        progress.show();
```

and the to dismiss use:

```
 progress.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

set a lisetner for you makeHTTPRequest() or AsyncTask
e.g:

```
  new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //show a dialog
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //dialog dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();
```